# Jenkinsfile using groovy classes not working when using lists

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a simple pipeline using Jenkinsfile to test classes and interfaces in Groovy but often I stock in situations that Jenkins return errors that not make any sense. For example, the next code implements a simple builder pattern:

```
class Configuration implements Serializable {
    ArrayList credentials
}

class ConfigurationBuilder implements Serializable {

    Configuration configuration

    ConfigurationBuilder() {
        configuration = new Configuration()
    }

    ConfigurationBuilder withCredentials(ArrayList credentials) {
        configuration.credentials = credentials
        return this
    }

    Configuration build() {
        return configuration
    }
}

node("commons") {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

    Configuration conf = builder.withCredentials(['test']).build()
    echo conf.credentials
}
```

The code above return this error when run-it on Jenkins:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:272)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:156)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:130)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {message=[test]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep
```

Any idea what's wrong?

I tried to implement it in the simplest way possible thinking that it was some limitation of Jenkins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed an `ArrayList` to an [`echo`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#echo-print-message) step. This step accepts only values of type `String`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
```

You can fix this error by calling `conf.credentials.toString()`

```
node("commons") {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

    Configuration conf = builder.withCredentials(['test']).build()
    echo conf.credentials.toString()
}
```